# Making Adjacency List in Scala with FoldLeft

Tags: scala, graph, immutability, scala-collections

Given this function

```
  def makeAdjacencyList(edgeList: Seq[(String, String)]): Map[String, Seq[String]] = {
    val emptyMap = Map[String, Seq[String]]().withDefaultValue(Seq[String]())

    edgeList.foldLeft(emptyMap) {
      case (acc, curr) => {
        acc + (curr._1 -> (acc(curr._1) :+ curr._2))
        acc + (curr._2 -> (acc(curr._2) :+ curr._1))
      }
    }
  }
```

It takes in a edgeList of an undirected graph, for example:

```
Vector((S1,E1), (S1,D1), (S2,E2), (S2,D1), (S3,E1), (S3,D2))
```

The function however gives an output of

```
[E1 -> [S1, S3], D1 -> [S1, S2], E2 -> [S2], D2 -> [S3]]
```

but I was expecting an output of

```
[S1 -> [E1, D1], S2 -> [E2, D1], S3 -> [E1], E1 -> [S1, S3], D1 -> [S1, S2], E2 -> [S2], D2 -> [S3]]
```

It seems like the first line of the foldLeft (`acc + (curr._1 -> (acc(curr._1) :+ curr._2))`) is being ignored and I am not quite sure why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both lines of code in the `case` block produces a result, but only the 2nd result is returned and becomes the next `acc` value.

This would fix it.

```
edgeList.foldLeft(emptyMap) {
  case (acc, curr) =>
    acc + (curr._1 -> (acc(curr._1) :+ curr._2)) +
          (curr._2 -> (acc(curr._2) :+ curr._1))
}
```

Here, on the other hand, is a different approach to achieve the desired output.

```
def makeAdjacencyList(edgeList: Seq[(String,String)]): Map[String,Seq[String]] =
  edgeList.flatMap(edge => Seq(edge, edge.swap))
          .groupMap(_._1)(_._2)
```